# Using R dplyr mutate to create a factor column using pre-declared levels

Tags: r, dplyr, factors, mutate

I've written R code to produce a periodic report that requires re-ordering of Week numbers such that I can filter and order by the most recent 10 weeks. To prevent errors and minimize hard-coded values, I prefer to declare this week order at the top of the script that sources the other several scripts used. Thus, I would like to define an ordered factor list and then use it to order the week number column later. RepEx below, but generally I am reordering all 52 weeks such that the most recent 10-week-period is last/largest, e.g. `new_levels <- factor(1:52, levels = c(29:52, 1:28), ordered=TRUE)`.

Side note: any advise on how better to handle grabbing the most recent (not necessarily greatest) 10-week period is welcomed. My struggle in the past is due to the roll-over near the end of the year (51, 52, 1, 2, 3,...).

Example:

```
new_levels <- factor(1:10, levels = c(8:10, 1:7), ordered=TRUE)

data <- tibble(Week = 1:10, ID = c("A","A","B","B","C","A","D","B","D","A"))

data <- data %>% mutate(Week2 = factor(Week, levels = new_levels, ordered = TRUE)) %>% arrange(Week2)
```

The ordered factor (new_levels) appears to be correct, but the behavior of arrange() and str() show that the ordering I want is not happening:

```
> new_levels
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
Levels: 8 < 9 < 10 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7
> data
# A tibble: 10 × 3
    Week ID    Week2
   <int> <chr> <ord>
 1     1 A     1    
 2     2 A     2    
 3     3 B     3    
 4     4 B     4    
 5     5 C     5    
 6     6 A     6    
 7     7 D     7    
 8     8 B     8    
 9     9 D     9    
10    10 A     10   
> str(data)
tibble [10 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Week : int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ ID   : chr [1:10] "A" "A" "B" "B" ...
 $ Week2: Ord.factor w/ 10 levels "1"<"2"<"3"<"4"<..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the "Side note" correctly. It sounds like it is a different question. Maybe you should consider asking a separate question with a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closer at your output, you will see you are not doing what you are expecting:

```r
data %>% 
  mutate(Week2 = factor(Week, levels = new_levels, ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
  pull(Week2)
#  [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
# Levels: 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7 < 8 < 9 < 10
```

This shows that `arrange` is working as expected. The issue comes from the fact that you are assigning `levels = new_levels`. What is the value of `new_levels`?

```r
new_levels
#  [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
# Levels: 8 < 9 < 10 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7
```

In this case it is a sequence of `1:10`. What you want is to assign the *levels* of `new_levels` to the levels of your new variable:

```r
data %>% 
  mutate(Week2 = factor(Week, levels = levels(new_levels), ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(Week2)
#     Week ID    Week2
#    <int> <chr> <ord>
#  1     8 B     8    
#  2     9 D     9    
#  3    10 A     10   
#  4     1 A     1    
#  5     2 A     2    
#  6     3 B     3    
#  7     4 B     4    
#  8     5 C     5    
#  9     6 A     6    
# 10     7 D     7
```

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense. Thank you very much for your very quick help!

Comment: You are welcome! Just a quick note, if all you are doing is sorting you do not need the `ordered` argument.

Answer (score 0):

The levels argument must be in the correct order (and defining the levels of new_levels does not reorder the vector itself). Also note that it is transformed to a character vector by the `factor` function, so (1) it is not necessary to define new_levels as a factor, (2) any factor levels you define for the vector passed to the levels argument are irrelevant, and (3) you can define new_levels as a numeric vector. You can simplify your code as follows:

```
data <- tibble(Week = 1:10, ID = c("A","A","B","B","C","A","D","B","D","A"))
data <- data %>%
  mutate(Week2 = factor(Week, levels = c(8:10, 1:7), ordered = TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(Week2)
```

Comment: I am trying to prevent explicitly listing the numbered levels in the mutate function--these are levels I use in a few places and want to define my levels only once in a visible place to prevent leaving the errant week numbers from the previous report cycle. This is why I am defining new_levels as a factor first. Thank you anyway.